# Split string to substring by N characters

Tags: ruby

I am just wondering if there is a better way to split string to substrings by N characters:

```
"something" (by 4 characters) -> ["some", "omet", "meth", "ethi", "thin", "hing"]
```

Here is my code:

```
n = 4
s = "something"
result = []

0.upto(s.size - n) do | idx |
    result << s[idx..idx+n-1]
end

p result
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"something".chars.each_cons(4).map(&:join)
=> ["some", "omet", "meth", "ethi", "thin", "hing"]
```

Comment: Maybe replace `split(//)` with `chars` .